# webdriverIO - add junit reporter

Tags: javascript, junit, webdriver-io, wdio-v4, webdriver-io-v4

I have an issue with adding the junit reporter to wdio.conf.js.

Whenever I try to implement any reporter I'm getting following output and my test is failing:

```
ERROR @wdio/local-runner: 2019-06-04T10:01:13.337Z
ERROR @wdio/local-runner: 2019-06-04T10:01:13.336Z 
ERROR @wdio/local-runner: Failed launching test session: 
TypeError: ReporterClass is not a constructor at BaseReporter.initReporter (/home/jawar/Project_webdriverio/node_modules/@wdio/runner/build/reporter.js:202:14) at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

This is how I add the reporter to the wdio.conf.js (https://webdriver.io/docs/jenkins.html)

```
  reporters: [
        'dot',
        ['junit', {
            outputDir: './'
        }]
    ],
```

I'm quite a beginner to this.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am having the same problem

Comment: As @flash47 already said, I actually reinstalled  the Junit package and it worked

Answer (score 3):

You must first install the Junit reporter package as per the following link before you configure it in wdio.conf.js: https://webdriver.io/docs/junit-reporter.html#installation